# DropDown box in ASP .Net MVC 3 Razor Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, drop-down-menu

i am new to ASP .NET and Particularly in ASP .Net MVC3 Razor...

i have created view for Clients and Executives in MVC3 Razor.

What i did is 1st i created Model called Clients.cs

```
namespace MVCInetClient.Model

{
    [Table(&quot;tbl_Customer&quot;)]
    public class Clients
    {
      [Required,Key,DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
      [Display(Name = &quot;Client ID&quot;)]
      public int ClientId { get; set; }
      [Required]
      [Display(Name = &quot;Client Name&quot;)]
      public string ClientName { get; set; }
      [Required]
      [Display(Name = &quot;Executive Name&quot;)]
      public string ExecutiveName { get; set; }
     [Required]
      [Display(Name = &quot;Contact Name&quot;)]
      public string ContactPerson { get; set; }
      [Display(Name = &quot;Address&quot;)]
      public string Add1 { get; set; }
      [Display(Name = &quot; &quot;)]
      public string Add2 { get; set; }
      [Display(Name = &quot; &quot;)]
      public string Add3 { get; set; }
      [Display(Name = &quot;Pincode&quot;)]
      public string Pin { get; set; }
      [Display(Name = &quot;State&quot;)]
      public string State { get; set; }
      [Display(Name = &quot;Country&quot;)]
      public string Country { get; set; }
      [Display(Name = &quot;Phone&quot;)]
      public string Phone { get; set; }
      [Required]
      [StringLength(10)]
      [RegularExpression(&quot;\\d+&quot;)]
      [Display(Name = &quot;Mobile&quot;)]
       public string Mobile { get; set; }
      [Display(Name = &quot;Fax&quot;)]
      public string Fax { get; set; }
      [Display(Name = &quot;Email&quot;)]
      public string Email { get; set; }
      [Display(Name = &quot;Website&quot;)]
      public string Web { get; set; }
   }

     public class ClientsDbContext : DbContext
     {
        public DbSet&lt;Clients&gt; Clients { get; set; }
         public DbSet&lt;Executives&gt; Executives{ get; set; }
     }
  }
```

After that i Created the Controller called ClientsController with Scaffolding Options,

```
Template : Controller With Read/Write actions and Views, using Entity Framework
Model Class : Clients (MVCInetClient.Models)
Data Context Class : ClientsDbContext (MVCInetClient.Models)
```

It Created View Create, Edit, Index, Delete Automatically and its working Fine too.

Similarly i did for model called Executives.cs

```
namespace MVCInetClient.Models
{
    [Table(&quot;tbl_Executive&quot;)]
    public class Executives
    {
        [Required, Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        [Display(Name = &quot;Executive ID&quot;)]
        public int ExecutiveId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = &quot;Executive Name&quot;)]
        public string ExecutiveName { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = &quot;Address&quot;)]
       public string Add1 { get; set; }
       [Display(Name = &quot; &quot;)]
        public string Add2 { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = &quot; &quot;)]
        public string Add3 { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = &quot;Pincode&quot;)]
        public string Pin { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = &quot;State&quot;)]
        public string State { get; set; }
       [Display(Name = &quot;Country&quot;)]
       public string Country { get; set; }
       [Display(Name = &quot;Phone&quot;)]
       public string Phone { get; set; }
       [Required]
       [StringLength(10)]
       [RegularExpression(&quot;\\d+&quot;)]
       [Display(Name = &quot;Mobile&quot;)]
       public string Mobile { get; set; }
       [Display(Name = &quot;Email&quot;)]
       public string Email { get; set; }

     }

     public class ExecutivesDbContext : DbContext
     {
        public DbSet&lt;Executives&gt; Executives { get; set; }
     }
 }
```

and this too Working Fine in all views(create, edit, delete)

What i need is, i need a Dropdown list of Executive name in Clients View instead of editor Field.

i looked some tutorials but i am confused... 
Please help me to solve it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are using EF Code First with MVC.

The simplest answer is that you need to a List of Executives, pass the list in a model back to your View, create a select list, and render a drop down list.

```
public ActionResult Execx()
{
    Model Model = new Model();
    Model.execList = dbcontext.Executives;

    return View(Model);
}
```

In your View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.execId, new SelectList(Model.execList, "ExecutiveId", "ExecutiveName "))
```

This is untested code. I slapped the pieces together to give you the idea.